# Maximal ideals in a polynomial ring over a noetherian ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noetherian

Let $R$ be a noetherian ring and let $R[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ be the polynomial ring in $n$ variables over $R$. Is it true that $\mathfrak{m}=(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is a maximal ideal in $R[x_1, \dots, x_n]$? If not, then what are the maximal ideals? Thanks.

Comment: hint: what is the quotient $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. is this always a field?

Comment: Right, $R[x_1, ..., x_n]/(x_1, ..., x_n)\cong R$ which is a field if and only if $R$ is a field. So, $(x_1, ..., x_n)$ is a maximal ideal if and only if $R$ is a field. In fact, $(x_1, ..., x_n)$ is not even a prime ideal unless $R$ is an integral domain.

Comment: yep, that's exactly right! :)

Comment: If $I$ is an ideal in $R[x_1, ..., x_n]$ and $f:R\to S$ is a ring morphism, then it is also true that $S\otimes_RI$ is an ideal in $S[x_1, .., x_n]=S\otimes_RR[x_1, .., x_n]$, right? However, if $I$ is a maximal ideal, for the same reason as in the above, $S\otimes_R I$ might not be maximal in $S[x_1, .., x_n]$.

Comment: yep, that's correct! for example take $R=k$ a field and $S=k[t]$,  where $f:R\to S$ is the inclusion, and consider the ideal $I=\langle x\rangle<k[x]$. then $S\otimes_R I$ corresponds to the ideal $\langle x\rangle$ of $S[x]=k[t,x]$, which is not maximal there